# Loop through Search-mailbox

Tags: powershell, csv, exchange-server

I have a requirement to search mailboxes for an email based on subject line and report if the email is in the Inbox or another folder. The below code works well for individual users.

```
Search-Mailbox -Identity "test@example.com" -SearchQuery ‘Subject:”Suspect email alert”‘ -TargetMailbox “admin” -TargetFolder “inbox”-LogOnly -LogLevel Full
```

The report received states if the email is in that particular mailbox and the location. This is great for one user, though I need to do this for over 500 users.

I have a csv file with a list of email addresses I need to check for this particular email and it's location. So I have imported the csv file to a variable. Then put the command in a foreach loop, though cannot get this working correctly.
Correction: updated to txt file a used get-content

```
$users = Get-Content -Path userslist.txt
foreach ($user in $users) {
Search-Mailbox $user -SearchQuery ‘Subject:”Suspect email alert”‘ -TargetMailbox “admin” -TargetFolder “inbox”-LogOnly -LogLevel Full }
```

How do I run through the list of users, so I can get one report rather than a report for each user individually. Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with the csv file formatting. imported text file and loop running fine. Would be good to get the results into one Search results file, rather than one for each loop.